# How to submit two forms in the same page in laravel using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have two forms in my view and one submit button :

```xml
<form method="POST" id="projet_casting_form" class="myForms" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting"/>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
            <select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="id_casting">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                @foreach($castings as $casting)
                    <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label>
            <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="id_modele_contrat">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                @foreach($models_contrat as $model_contrat)
                    <option data-id="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}" value="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}">{{$model_contrat->modele_contrat}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

// Second form

```xml
<form method="POST" id="projet_casting_form" class="myForms" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting"/>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
            <select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="id_casting">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                @foreach($castings as $casting)
                    <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label>
            <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="id_modele_contrat">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                @foreach($models_contrat as $model_contrat)
                    <option data-id="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}" value="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}">{{$model_contrat->modele_contrat}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

// And Submit Button

```xml
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-1">Add</button>
```

I'm trying to insert into database the two forms into two different tables,
in other words the first form stores into table and the second form stores into another table.

So I'm using the following code Ajax :

```xml
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    
    $('#submit').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({  
            url: "{{ route('ajout_projet.store') }}",  
            method: "POST",  
            data: $('#projetform').serialize(),
            type:'json',
        }); 
    });  
});
</script>
```

And the following controller :

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax()) {
        $date_tournage = $request['date_tournage'];
        $time_tournage = strtotime($date_tournage);
        $date = date('Y-m-d', $time_tournage);
        $date_diffusion = $request['date_premiere_diffusion'];
        $time_diffusion = strtotime($date_diffusion);
        $datee_diffusion = date('Y-m-d',$time_diffusion);
        
        $rules = array(
            'numero_projet' => 'required',
            'id_client' => 'required',
            'id_agence_conseil' => 'required',
            'id_agence_production' => 'required',
            'id_agence_casting' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'date_tournage' => 'required',
            'date_premiere_diffusion' => 'required'
        );
    
        $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    
        if ($error->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $error->errors()->all()]);
        }
    
        $projets = new Projet();
        $projets->numero_projet = $request['numero_projet'];
        $projets->id_client = $request['id_client'];
        $projets->id_agence_conseil = $request['id_agence_conseil'];
        $projets->id_agence_production = $request['id_agence_production'];
        $projets->id_agence_casting = $request['id_agence_casting'];
        $projets->description = $request['description'];
        $projets->date_tournage = $date;
        $projets->date_premiere_diffusion = $datee_diffusion;
        $projets->id_filiale = Auth::user()->id_filiale;
        $projets->id_createur = Auth::user()->id;
        $projets->save();
                   
        // Add Projet-Casting
                     
        $id_projet = $projets->id;
        $id_casting = $request->id_casting;
        $id_contrat = 1;
    
        $projetscastings = [
            'id_projet'=> $id_projet,
            'id_casting'=> $id_casting,
            'id_contrat'=> $id_contrat,
        ];
    }
    
    return dd($projetscastings);
}
```

But When I execute my code, the data of the first form is inserted into its table but for the second form , I'm getting :

```
array:3 [
  "id_projet" => null
  "id_casting" => null
  "id_contrat" => 1
]
```

And when I did :

```
data:console.log($('#projetform').serialize()),
```

I got : `_token=T1FQQUFlrXd47Cbm7FSNISPfbIArxsZnd0QLEVxr&id_projet=&numero_projet=jh&id_client=1&id_agence_conseil=1&id_agence_production=1&id_agence_casting=1&description=ok&date_tournage=06%2F02%2F2021&date_premiere_diffusion=06%2F24%2F2021`

So the inputs of the second form are not token.

How can I pass the two forms in the same request ajax ?

If you have any ides I will be grateful

Thank you in advance

Comment: console.log() the data you're sending via JS and you will see what is missing and what is sent.

Comment: @N69S , When I did  `console.log(data)` , I get : `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: do `console.log($('#projetform').serialize())`

Comment: I get : `_token=T1FQQUFlrXd47Cbm7FSNISPfbIArxsZnd0QLEVxr&id_projet=&numero_projet=jh&id_client=1&id_agence_conseil=1&id_agence_production=1&id_agence_casting=1&description=ok&date_tournage=06%2F02%2F2021&date_premiere_diffusion=06%2F24%2F2021` , The elements of the second form are not token

Comment: then you have your lead. Try and change how you get your data with JS. TLDR that line need to be worked out more. Edit your question to make it more specific about what you need help with and add what you have tried too.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like below way

**First Form**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{your_action}}" id="delete_something" class="myForms" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Second Form**

```
<form method="POST" action={{your_action}} id="add_something" class="myForms" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Submit Button**

```
<button type="button" onclick="submitData()" class="btn btn-primary mb-1">Submit</button>
```

In Javascript use like below code

```
<script>
    function submitData(){
        document.getElementById("delete_something").submit();
        document.getElementById("add_something").submit();
        // Or jQuery
        // $("#delete_something").submit();
        // $("#add_something").submit();
    }
</script>
```